# How to resolve getting Timeout java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 5000000000 NANOSECONDS

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-webflux

I want to write a async api that return 202 Accepted after getting a request. Then after that it should send n Post request per second for halt-time seconds. This is my attempt at the problem.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/stress")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
private Mono<?> stressPostLog(@RequestBody StressTest request) throws InterruptedException {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            sendBatchRequest(request);
            return null;
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    
}

private void sendBatchRequest(StressTest requestParams) throws InterruptedException {
    successfulRequest.set(0);

    long haltTimeMillis = requestParams.getHalt_time() * 1000;
    log.info("Halt Time Millis = " + haltTimeMillis );
    Integer count = 0;

    long initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long currTime;
    do {
        Thread.sleep(1000); //! Sleep time is subjected to system
        for(int i = 0; i < requestParams.getRequest_per_second(); i++)
        {
            AuditSchema request = AuditSchema.generateRandomValue(requestParams.getRequest_size());
            Mono<?> response = postAndIncrement(request);
            response.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).subscribe();
            count++;
        }
        currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("Time duration = " + ( currTime - initTime));
    }while((currTime - initTime) < haltTimeMillis);

    log.info("Request Send = {} and Response Succeed = {}", count, successfulRequest);
}

private Mono<?> postAndIncrement(AuditSchema request) {
    return this.client.post()
            .uri("v1/log")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
                log.info("Request suceeded {}", clientResponse.statusCode());
                successfulRequest.getAndIncrement();
                return Mono.empty();
            });
}
```

however the calls are not executed async and after 5s it gets terminated by error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 5000000000 NANOSECONDS
```

How to write this using spring webflux.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you use `fromCallable` doesn't mean that `Callable` gets executed asynchronously. Use `fromFuture` instead:

```
return Mono.fromFuture(CompletableFuture.runAsyc(() -> sendBatchRequest(request)))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
```

You can provide an `Executor` (or `ExecutorService`) to `runAsync` instead of using a common fork-join pool if needed.

Comment: This does not address the issue that 202 not posted before processing and I am still gettting timeout error.

Comment: You're right, you probably need to decouple the return value from the async processing. Because your method returns a `Mono`, the HTTP response is sent when the mono completes. Try returning `void` instead, and let the mono do its work in the background.

Answer (score 0):

To address the issue of the HTTP 202, modify your method to return `void` and let the asynchronous processing happen in the background.